# the code works in Eigen 3.2 but fails in Eigen 3.4. Anyone know the reason？

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

the following code can be compiled successfuly by Eigen 3.2: g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -isystem /eigen-3.2.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    typedef Eigen::MatrixXcf CMatrix;
    typedef Eigen::Array<CMatrix, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> CMMatrix;
    CMMatrix a = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix b = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the above code by Eigen 3.4， it failed: g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test  -isystem /eigen-3.4.0. And the error information is :

```
ambiguous overload for 'operator+' (operand types are 'CMMatrix {aka Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>}' and 'CMMatrix {aka Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>}')
     CMMatrix c = a + b;
```

Anyone know why? How can I fix the code by using Eigen 3.4?
What's more, I change the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    typedef Eigen::MatrixXcf CMatrix;
    typedef Eigen::Array<CMatrix, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> CMMatrix;
    CMMatrix a = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix b = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix c = a;
    c += b;
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, the above code can be compiled successfully. What's the reason?
How can I fix the code by using  Eigen 3.4 elegently, but not the way "c=a,c+=b;".
Thanks a lot!

---

The full eror information is as follows:

```
test_map.cpp:13:20: ambiguous overload for operator+ (operand types are CMMatrix {aka Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>} and CMMatrix {aka Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>})
         CMMatrix c = a + b;
                      ~~^~~
    In file included from /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/Core:19:0,
                     from test_map.cpp:2:
    /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/CommonCwiseBinaryOps.h:27:28: candidate: const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, typename Eigen::internal::traits<OtherDerived>::Scalar>, const Derived, const OtherDerived> Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>::operator+(const Eigen::ArrayBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>; Derived = Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>; typename Eigen::internal::traits<OtherDerived>::Scalar = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>; typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>]
     EIGEN_MAKE_CWISE_BINARY_OP(operator+,sum)
                                ^
    /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:1339:4: in definition of macro \u2018EIGEN_MAKE_CWISE_BINARY_OP
       (METHOD)(const EIGEN_CURRENT_STORAGE_BASE_CLASS<OtherDerived> &other) const \
        ^~~~~~
    /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/ArrayCwiseBinaryOps.h:241:29: candidate: const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, typename Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T> > >::value>::type>, const Derived, const typename Eigen::internal::plain_constant_type<Derived, typename Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T> > >::value>::type>::type> Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>::operator+(const T&) const [with T = Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>; Derived = Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1>; typename Eigen::internal::plain_constant_type<Derived, typename Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T> > >::value>::type>::type = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>, -1, -1> >; typename Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::has_ReturnType<Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T, Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, T> > >::value>::type = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>; typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, -1>]
     EIGEN_MAKE_SCALAR_BINARY_OP(operator+,sum)
                                 ^
    /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:1365:4: in definition of macro EIGEN_MAKE_SCALAR_BINARY_OP_ONTHERIGHT
       (METHOD)(const T& scalar) const { \
        ^~~~~~
    /eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/ArrayCwiseBinaryOps.h:241:1: in expansion of macro \u2018EIGEN_MAKE_SCALAR_BINARY_OP
     EIGEN_MAKE_SCALAR_BINARY_OP(operator+,sum)
```

Comment: And if you continue reading the error, what does it say about the first and the second operator definitions?

Comment: It looks like to have two candidates, one is a class member and another one is in Eigen namespace. I guess removing `using namespace Eigen;` might fix the issue.

Comment: @273K I remove the 'using namespace Eigen' ，it can not work as previously.

Comment: The same error occurs already with 3.3.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Gc4qhvs3o

Comment: @tueda I find the solution. Please see the answer.

Comment: @273K I find the solution. Please see the answer

Comment: @tueda I find the solution. Please see the answer

Answer (score 0):

I find the following code can work.

```
 int main()
{
    typedef Eigen::MatrixXcf CMatrix;
    typedef Eigen::Array<CMatrix, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> CMMatrix;
    CMMatrix a = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix b = CMMatrix::Constant(4, 4,CMatrix::Zero(3, 3));
    CMMatrix c = a.matrix() + b.matrix();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a description. An answer isn't useful if you need a diff tool to find the differences.

Comment: I just change the orign code "CMMatrix c = a + b;“ into " CMMatrix c = a.matrix() + b.matrix();". Then the code works.